# Cross-platform screenshot tool

Tags: cross-platform, screen-recording, screenshot, gif

I am having trouble finding a cross-platform tool that works on Windows, Mac & Linux, and lets you take screenshots, GIFs & screencasts of any part of your screen.

Most of the tools that I have found that are cross-platform either only work on Windows & Mac or can only take screenshots but no GIFs or screencasts.

Comment: Are GIFs a make/break? old, clunky, large, possibly prone to copyright problems with the technology (which is why PNG was invented)?

Comment: Do you mind if you have separate software for screenshots and screencasts?

Comment: Ideally, would love to have a single software. But, if none exists then separate software would be fine.